# Multiple wcf services in one implementation

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a two interfaces:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IRemotePlayer), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IRemotePlaybackCtrl
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true)]
    bool SignIn(Guid id, string key, int number);
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IRemoteStreamer), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IRemoteStreamerCtrl
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true)]
    bool RegisterStreamer();
}
```

both implemented in single class. I need to create WCF service self-host and `netTcpBinding` endpoints on ports `9001` and `9002` (or single port `9001` if it possible).
Both services are duplex and using sessions.
The configuration file is:

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <services>        
        <service behaviorConfiguration="svcBehavior" name="CtrlSvcSelf.SL.Player.RemoteCtrl">
          <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9001/streamCtrl" binding="netTcpBinding"
            contract="Remote.IRemoteStreamerCtrl" />
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9001/streamCtrl" />
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
        </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="svcBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/> 
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

It works fine.
How can I modify configuration file to get needed result? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Have you tried adding a second `<endpoint>`?

Comment: the problem was I trying to add a `<baseAddress>` with same binding (tcp). So only adding new `<endpoint>` I have solve the problem. Thanks!